# Error when building existing solution in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Hy guys,

I got one existing project from my co-worker. I opened the folder in VS as web site. When I build it and try to run I get the following message-
 Warning C:\Users......: ASP.NET runtime error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Error  -  Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I have a Visual Studio 2012, registered as student version, target framework is 2.0

Comment: your error description is very general, could you put the the code where the error appears?

Comment: Problem is that I didn't make any changes to the project that is working, just not on my computer. Warning shows to the first line of aspx file - <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="...aspx.cs" Inherits="ActivationDuration" %>

Answer (score 0):

Try to check your project reference to load well, not missing reference (you can check in folder "Reference"), or sometime this error because your object is not initialize [blank value], you can add images to give us detail information for your issue.

Comment: Missing references (if not loaded in runtime from code) should give a compiler error while trying to build the solution.

Answer (score -1):

That is called a Null Reference, you (the code) try to use an object which is not created/initialised yet.
Its impossible to give you an answer which would fix your issue, you will have to debug the code yourself.
When the exception occurs, visual studio should ask you if you want to 'break' or 'continue'.   Choose break and check where in the code the error is, then take it from there.

```
//Example:
AClassofSomeSort myObj2 = new AClassofSomeSort();
myObj2.DoSomething(); //Totally fine, cause the myObj2 have been initialised.

AClassofSomeSort myObj;
myObj.DoSomething(); //Oh noes, the 'myObj' is not created! Exception is thrown.
```

Comment: Problem is that I didn't make any changes to the project that is working, just not on my computer. Warning shows to the first line of aspx file - <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="...aspx.cs" Inherits="ActivationDuration" %>

Comment: Does it work on every other computer tested or just your co-workers?
He could have some file/s or settings on hes computer that have not been saved to the solution.
Its not the warnings you are after, you want the program to break when you get the error, so that you can pinpoint it to what variable it is that have the issue.

Comment: I started debugging, it opened IE and showed this - http://tinypic.com/r/24zlyyw/8

Comment: It seems that the reference to Oracle.DataAccess seems to be having issues. Maybe you are using another version than your co-worker? I'm not very used to asp.net, so I can't help very much with the aspx specific issues. I would ask your co-worker to take a look at it, and see if you guys have the same references.
Could also be a good idea to see to that you guys are using the same target framework.

Comment: I installed ODAC with Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio now.  Now I get the following error in IE - <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>

Comment: i think you installed a differnt ODAC version, have you checked if all references are properly added to your solution?